# Spring (with Jade) Resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, jade4j

**The Problem**

My spring-boot application recently changed routing from *host/endpoint* to *host/middle/endpoint*. Since the change, I am running into an issue where the resources are not being found relative to the new url structure. Before, I could reference resources like css stylesheets like *link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')*, but now the logger shows an error saying it can't find the resource at */middleman/css/style.css*.

From my research, I have found that what I need to do is use a resource handler registry. I have created one (as shown below) but it doesn't seem to be working. I think the problem is that even though I now have the resource registry, I am not referencing resources in the registry. What is the proper way to solve this problem and have all resources point load from the same place regardless of the endpoint? I very well may be missing some obvious piece of SOP

**Note**: This is all a dumbed down representation of my project in order to give the idea of what is going on without giving unnecessary information.

**Project Structure**

```
src
  main
    java
      com.mystuff.cool
        configurations
          ResourceConfiguration.java
        controllers
          RoutingController.java
        application
          Application.java
  resources
    static
      css
        footer.css
        style.css
      images
        place1.png
        location1.png
        spot1.png
        favicon.ico
      javascripts
        layout.js
    templates
      home.jade
```

**Application Class**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.packages"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSAMLSSO
@Configuration
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{ Application.class, ServiceConfig.class, ResourceConfiguration.class}, args);
    }
}
```

**Resource Configuration**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class RoutingController
{    
    @RequestMapping("/house/home")
    public String home(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Home is where the heart is");
        commonModelTribs(model);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**Home Page**

```
doctype html
html
  title Place-spedia #{title}
  link(rel='icon', href='images/favicon.ico')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')  
  script(src='javascripts/layout.js')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/footer.css')
body
    div#footer-icons
        a(href='place1')
            img#place1(src="images/place1.png")
        a(href='location1')
            img#location1(src="images/location1.png")
        a(href='spot1')
            img#spot1(src='images/spot1.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring boot, you don't need to worry about the resource configuration since you are already configuring the resource directory through the auto configuration. The default behavior for the autoconfiguration is to look within `resources/static`.

Your issue is with your href values, try inserting a leading forward slash:

```
link(rel='icon', href='/images/favicon.ico')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')  
script(src='javascripts/layout.js')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/footer.css')
```

Spring is routing your application to a new relative path, so by putting the leading `/` in your `href` attributes, you are telling the router to look absolutely within the `static` directory instead of relatively from the `middle` directory.